# How to list Kirana store/cafe for particular postcode on Django Framework?

Tags: python, django, project

Based on postcode or location given by user how do I retrieve the list of nearby Kirana stores/cafes? I don't know from where to start the code.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/

Comment: use Django treebeard https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ it will create tree view of the model. so you can find siblings of that area(means nearby areas of selected area)